# How to add title in Netbeans (java)?

Tags: java, netbeans, title

Just can't figure this out in my GUI, I know it's probably simple but thought I'd ask.

I assume I need something in this code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new myGUI().setVisible(true);


        }
    });
}
```

Thanks.

Edit - for some reason public static etc. isn't showing up above - but you probably don't need that.

Comment: so whats the question?

Comment: How can I add a title to my GUI in Netbeans. And whereabouts do I put the code? Can't see JFrame mentioned in my code apart from once so I JFrame.setTitle("example"); won't work.

Comment: u r on right track, you need to setTitle inside the above method. however to be able to help we need some more code.

Comment: Thanks. Done that and it now says that it can't be referenced from a static method. I'm getting closer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not showing us the whole code, so this is only a guess, but probably a good one: I assume that `myGUI` is a subclass of `JFrame`, and you want to call `setTitle()` on it. Something like

```
myGUI m = new myGUI();
m.setTitle("The Title");
m.setVisible(true);
```

You'd put these three lines in place of the one `new myGUI().setVisible(true);` .

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Netbeans do you have a screen/form in which you have been designing your Frame?

If so open the navigator toolbar and right click on your frame, select properties and look for the one called title, and type in your text there.

Otherwise you will need to add something like

```
 myGui.setTitle("A title") // assuming its a JFrame
```